# Какая высота у TextView?

Tags: android-sdk, android

Нужно в приложении указать размер текста = 640px(ровно половину от тестируемого устройства с разрешение 720x1280, плотностью пикселей 2(xhdpi), в настройках размер текста стоит стандартная). Вот разметка:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_orange_dark">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="A"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="320sp"
        android:onClick="onClick"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="A"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="320sp"
        android:onClick="onClick"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_green_dark"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Размер TextView1 и TextView2 указываю 320sp, внутри обработчика onClick у них вызываю getHeight(), возвращает значение 850px, разве не должно возвращать 640?  Так же видно на экране, что текст занимает больше половины. Режим отображения установлен Fulscreen. Вот как это выглядит:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**UPD**

Размер установил как sp. Так же обновил значение и макет для наглядности. Добавил скриншот.

Comment: как насчет отступов?

Comment: @metalurgus getHeight() я же вызываю у TextView

Comment: @iamtihonov Возможно это связано с тем, что у вас есть буквы в верхнем регистре и из-за них значение размера вашей View изменяется

Comment: @BORSHEVIK если указать текст в нижнем регистре, ничего не меняется.

Comment: @iamtihonov тогда я согласен с saturov, вполне вероятно, что размер View больше, т.к. метод View.getHieght() возвращает размер View, а не текста. вызовите для вашей TextView метод getTextSize (), думаю он вернёт ваше значение

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы указываете размер самого текста, а считываете высоту элемента `TextView`. Разумеется, это разные вещи. Не говоря уже о том, что указывать размер текста в `px` вообще некорректно. `px` вообще желательно нигде не использовать. Для размеров элементов - `dp`, для размера текста - `sp`.

[Здесь подробнее](http://startandroid.ru/ru/materialy/pamjatka/40-edinitsy-izmerenija-chem-otlichaetsja-dp-dip-ot-px-screen-density)

Comment: Можно указать и например 160sp, при плотности телефона(xhdpi), выйдет 320px. Но как мне заранее тогда узнать сколько будет занимать TextView по высоте?

Comment: @iamtihonov Текст нужно указывать не в dp и не в px, а в sp

Comment: @iamtihonov да вот этим атрибутом играйте android:layout_height="wrap_content"! Задайте высоту явно, тогда и будете знать заранее, какой высоты будет TextView.

Comment: То что можно на глаз прикинуть это понятно, хотелось бы точного знания  значения, сколько будет текст занимать.

Comment: @iamtihonov по вашим ответам я предполагаю, что вы вообще не понимаете, как формируется размер TextView при значении атрибутов габаритов "wrap_content". Если стоит wrap_content - размер вьюхи будет подгоняться под размер текста. И вы заранее никак не узнаете его. Чтобы знать заранее - нужно ручками его выставить. И тогда размер текста не будет влиять на размер TextView.

Comment: Просто допустим есть макет в котором размер шрифта 320px и мне нужно его перенести в app, тогда выходит просто рассчитать необходимое значение не выйдет.

Comment: setTextSize() метод для задания размера шрифта, можете и конкретно в пикселях задавать, если в макете указано, но это неправильно, т.к. у разных телефонов могут быть разные плотности пикселей, поэтому задавать нужно в sp

Comment: @iamtihonov я близок к тому, чтобы сдаться. я не понимаю, что вы рассчитываете и зачем. просто задать размер текста - это для вас не вариант? и что за макет такой дурацкий? 320px - это невероятно гигантский размер текста. Про то, что в px текст не верстается - вам уже сказали неоднократно.

Comment: @BORSHEVIK думаю можно и в пикселях указать в коде, главное рассчитать на сколько изменился экран по вертикали(найти отношение) и умножить на размер шрифта.

Comment: @saturov я уже писал в макете в px, в приложении я юзаю sp. Указал px в макете для простоты

Comment: @saturov про размер это я для примера=)

Comment: @iamtihonov "думаю можно и в пикселях указать в коде, главное рассчитать на сколько изменился экран по вертикали(найти отношение) и умножить на размер шрифта." Вот чтобы не городить свой велосипед и не заниматься таким бредом и придумали "SP"

Comment: @BORSHEVIK так и сколько тогда нужно указать sp если размер шрифта 320px?

Comment: @iamtihonov А для какого разрешения было выбрано это значение? Как минимум вы бы могли выбрать на глаз нужный вам размер, я сильно сомневаюсь, что это бы как-то нарушило дизайнерскую мысль

Comment: @BORSHEVIK 1280x720(xhdpi), да на глаз всегда можно.

Comment: Создаёте эмулируемое устройство в вашей среде разработки, задаёте ему экран с вашим разрешением и пишите небольшой код, который посчитает вам ваше значение, на вход принимает в пикселях и контекст, а на выходе в SP. КОД: public static float pixelsToSp(Context context, float px) {
    float scaledDensity = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().scaledDensity;
    return px/scaledDensity;
}                                                                                  Далее вы используете эту цифру для задания размера текста в SP

Comment: @saturov просто указать дополнительно android:layout_height="160dp" не выйдет, тогда текст будет обрезаться

Comment: @BORSHEVIK код рассчитает значение 160sp, но высота view будет другой

Comment: @iamtihonov Высота View будет какой нужно

Comment: @BORSHEVIK да 425px

Comment: @BORSHEVIK по этой формуле выходит sp = 188.23529, что больше 160sp. В итоге текст ещё выше получается, а должен быть 300px

Comment: @iamtihonov Этот код позволяет вывести нужноге значение SP, когда вы знаете PX для конкретного разрешения экрана, далее это значение суйте в код и везде текст будет одинакового размера, то, что они разные, это норма

Comment: @BORSHEVIK рассчитываю 320px, у девайса с высотой 1280px это ровно четверть, проганяю 320px через формулу получаю 160sp, задаю этот размер TextView, а она занимает больше места чем 1/4

Comment: TexView задаёте, или размеру текста?

Comment: TexView  в разметке указываю textSize = 160sp

Comment: @iamtihonov Тогда не знаю, можете тут поискать http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6263250/convert-pixels-to-sp